# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid primitive conversion from boolean to int

Tags: android, proguard

my status

1. Android 6.0 crash, other android version normal
2. if i set minifyEnabled = false , no crash

   - if i set minifyEnabled = true  , will crash
   - when activity is not visibility the error appear
3. it's like error when saving state

my err is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid primitive conversion from boolean to int
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:946)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1442)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1319)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSparseArray(Parcel.java:778)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1347)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:127)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1148)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at f.r.c.i.a.e.invoke(ActivityManagerHook.java:89)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
at $Proxy7.activityStopped(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: mind posting code?

Comment: Also, did you read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code ?